# DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS USE in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, scripting, if-not-exists

I always was used following header in files that defined database in MySql:

```
DROP DATABASE   IF     EXISTS base;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS base;
USE base;
```

In PostgreSQL there are the following problems.

`IF NOT EXISTS` is not definied, `USE` is not defined. Instead of this we can use `\c` but it doesn't work if I write it in executable sql file. Additionally I cant remove database If I am connected with this database.

Is there any alternative of these commands in `PostgreSQL`. I want to have idempotent sql code that create database if this database is not defined and totally clean it if this database exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql

Comment: To be honest, idempotency in SQL DDL is an illusion anyway. Does `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` create the *same* table? Or automagically alter the target table to match the new definition? Nope. It just hopes the table with the same name happens to have the definition you want. I think you're better off looking at schema migration tools like Liquibase.

Comment: It is great folly to think that SQL code written for one RDBMs (MySQL, Pg, Oracle, SS, etc) can be used by another.  You have found the first of many incompatibilities.  There is a "standard", and many vendors come 'close' to accepting it.  (Recommend MariaDB 10 for a MySQL-compatible engine that also honors the standard.)